# При нажатии на кнопку, можно будет изменить шрифт текста у textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть textbox и есть кнопка, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Используйте обработчик события `Button.Click`. В дизайнере выделите кнопку, и нажмите по ней двойным кликом. Создастся обработчик. В нём напишите код, который меняет шрифт текстбоксу.

Comment: @aepot а можно реализовать так, чтобы вылезало окно и там уже можно это все указать?

Answer (score 1):

Заводим обработчика события кнопки, либо 2 раза кликнуть по кнопке в дизайнере окна, либо в свойствах кнопки выбрать события и навесить события на Click.
И в обработчик пишем например так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, 20, textBox1.Font.Style);
}
```

Comment: Автор хочет, "чтобы вылезало окно". Будет здорово, если покажете пример с использованием [FontDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.fontdialog?view=net-5.0)